# Delete entries of a Map<Long, List<Object>>

Tags: java, java-stream

after hours of research I can't find the solution of my problem. I have a `Map<String, List<User>>` and I want to remove some items of the Map based on some values in the List.

I have to following User class

```
public class User {
    public String firstName,
    public Integer age

    public boolean is50() {
       return this.age.equals(50);
    }

}
```

And I have a Map as this :

```
Map<String, List<User> myMap = new HashMap<>();

myMap.put("A", new ArrayList<>());
myMap.get("A").add(new User("John", 50));
myMap.get("A").add(new User("Bob", 30));

myMap.put("B", new ArrayList<>());
myMap.get("B").add(new User("Sam", 25));
myMap.get("B").add(new User("Sarah", 56));

myMap.put("C", new ArrayList<>());
myMap.get("C").add(new User("Gill", 15));
myMap.get("C").add(new User("Jim", 20));
```

Now, I want to remove entries of Map if at least One user in a List age is 50. Also, I want to use Java 8 features to achieve this.

I've found that there is a `removeIf` function but I can't make it works with Lists.

I've tried something like this :

```
Map<String, List<User> filteredMap = myMap
                                 .enrySet()
                                 .removeIf(e -> e.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .filter(user -> user::is50)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Of course that doesn't work :(

The excepted Output is a filteredMap with only B et C keys with all users (the A key must be deleted because John has 50 yrs old)

Thx for your help and hope it is clear ;)

Comment: Stream.anyMatch Javadoc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).

Comment: So the prevoius map should not be altered?

Comment: @michalk It depends on your intent. If you don't want the previous map to be altered, simply make a copy. I've demonstrated this within my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick:

```
myMap.entrySet()
    .removeIf(e -> e.getValue()
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(User::is50));
```

Do note that entrySet() modifications (removeIf) affect the map backed by the entry set. So, you either have to make a copy of the map and run this on the copy, or let the first map (`myMap`) be modified.

As for making copies of your map, you can simply do:

```
Map<String, List<User>> copy = new HashMap<>(myMap);
```

**EDIT:**
As per @Holger's suggestion, the better way to do in-place removal is as following:

```
myMap.values()
    .removeIf(v -> v.stream()
        .anyMatch(User::is50));
```

The reason this is better is fourfold:

1. You can eliminate a call to `getValue` since `values` provides the value set directly.
2. It communicates intent more clearly - there is less of a logical leap between `values` and a value than between `entrySet` and a value.
3. It's more concise *and* is not an anti-pattern (e.g. the use of `peek` outside of debugging is an anti-pattern, despite sometimes being more concise).
4. It still works, since the Collection returned by `values` is [backed by the map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()).

Comment: I’d take the OP’s statement “I want to remove some items of the Map” literally, so `removeIf` is the right tool, as modifying the original map is the intended operation. However, the same applies to the `values()` view, which makes calling `getValue()` on each entry obsolete, `myMap.values().removeIf(l -> l.stream() .anyMatch(User::is50));`

Answer (score 7):

Simply use [`Stream::noneMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) for your nested Stream :

```
Map<String, List<User>> filteredMap = myMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .noneMatch(User::is50)
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

filteredMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));
```

The output is :

```
B
C
```

In this solution `myMap` will stay unaffected since I use `stream` out of `entrySet` and then collect it. `Set::removeIf` would alter your previous map since `Map::entrySet` returns `Set` of entries which backs your original `Map`.

Comment: This approach is more efficient than mine, because it first filters and then copies, even if it's more verbose. For this reason, +1.

Comment: That's excatly what I looked for ! @Avi your solution works but indeed I rather choose this immutable one ;)

Comment: @PierreJones consider accepting one of the answers if any of these answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, you'll have to operate on the EntrySet. You can convert that to a stream and collect back into a new map like so:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
             .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().noneMatch(User::is50))
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Map EntrySet to parse your map, then parse the list in each entry

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<User> entry : myMap.entrySet())
{
    boolean toDelete = false;
    for (User user : entry.getValue())
    {
        if (user.age == 50)
            toDelete = true;
    }
    if (toDelete)
        myMap.remove(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Everybody can do this using loops :)

Comment: This answer the question, and I do not see anything in the question about not using loops. And this is easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: Thx, it will be helpful for beginners but I looked for a Java 8 - Immutable solution ;)

Comment: …except that this is wrong, as you *must not* modify the map you’re iterating over. If you want to remove elements while iterating, you have to create an `Iterator` manually and only remove element by calling the iterator’s `remove()` method.